# Getting error when trying to apply a version to a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I am trying to create a pivot table with VBA using the code below. If I omit the last line (the default version line), it works great but unfortunately creates the older/classic view of the pivot table, and that's not working for our users (who want the newer/updated pivot table format). When I add in the `DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14` line, I get an "Invalid procedure call or argument" error. From all my research, it seems like this should work, so I can't figure out why it's giving me that error.

```
Set wksh_pivot = wkbk_to.Worksheets.Add
    wkbk_to.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=wksh_to.Range("A1").CurrentRegion).CreatePivotTable _
      TableDestination:=wksh_pivot.Range("A3"), TableName:="PivotTableName" _
      , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

Comment: Use `PivotCaches.Create` not `.Add` then you can specify the version for the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More detailed version than my comment:

If you use `PivotCaches.Add`, the resultant cache will always have a `.Version` value of `xlPivotTableVersion10`, and so you can't then try and create a later version pivot table from it.

If you use `PivotCaches.Create` you can specify what version you want (in the absence of other information it will default to `xlPivotTableVersion12` I believe).